# The frequency in specific column of a csv file: key error

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Write a function freq_column that takes as input a filename that is a string, and a column name that is a string. It should read in the csv file that has filename, and return a dictionary that has as keys that are any unique items that occur in the column with the name indicated, and as values the frequency of the item. You should assume that the csv file has a header row.

```
Item,Price,Location
1,2.50,Melbourne
1,1.50,Perth
2,5.52,Melbourne
1,2.50,Sydney
2,1.00,Perth
3,6.12,Brisbane

freq_column("data.csv", "Item") 
{'1': 3, '2': 2, '3': 1}
freq_column("data.csv", "Location")
{'Melbourne': 2, 'Perth': 2, 'Sydney': 1, 'Brisbane': 1}
```

Here is the code i wrote

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict as dd 

def freq_column(file_name, column):
    with open(file_name) as readfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(readfile)
        dic=dd(int)
        for row in reader:
            dic[row[column]]+=1
    return dic
```

When i tested my code, there is an error:" Column name doesn't exist. Your submission raised an exception of type KeyError. "

Could anyone please help with that?

Comment: When I run the program with the given data, it works as expected, so could you include what you are testing the program with (the function calls used etc...)